# Filter a given array in angular 4 without using another array and display it in the same component

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have an array of students with their names and results.

```
studentResults = [
{name: 'Adam', result : 'Passed'},
{name: 'Alan', result : 'Failed'},
{name : 'Sandy', result : 'Passed'}, 
{name: 'Max', result : 'Passed'},
{name : 'Woody', result : 'Failed'}];
```

I want to display in a component a list of students who have passed the exams on the left side and those who have failed on the right side. How will I filter the array and display the records without using another array ?

Comment: You **should** use two other arrays. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Maybe you should filter your array and create one array with your students in `Passed` status and another one with `Failed` status. After that, only display the arrays.

Answer (score 2):

you can create one `filter` pipe and use it in template like so

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterByResult'
})
export class FilterByResultPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, result: 'Passed' | 'Failed', args?: any): any {
    return value.filter(student => student.result === result);
  }
}
```

in template

```
<div *ngFor="let student of studentResults | filterByResult: 'Passed'">
        {{student.name}}
<div>

<div *ngFor="let student of studentResults | filterByResult: 'Failed'">
        {{student.name}}
<div>
```

Comment: Calling methods from html is not a good idea. Angular Change Detection mechanism will call that method many times.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner it is suggested in angular documentation to use methods like filter or order in component like so

Comment: You can use filters, pipes. That's fine. But it is different from your example. Yours will result in too many times method execution. You can see it by yourself if you write `console.log` within those methods.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner yeah you are right, I have updated my answer to pipe :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ngIf inside an ngFor loop:

```
<div *ngFor="let student of studentResults">
    <ng-container *ngIf="student.result == 'Passed'">
        {{student.name}}
    </ng-container>
<div>
```

And do the same for the failed div on the right side

Answer (score 1):

you can use pipes to the same array in your view and pass to it the key you want to filter. 
I made an example for you in stackblitz for your case: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-array-pipes?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Updated: 
Here is the Code snippet for the pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(data: any, key: string, value: string): any {
    if(!data || data.length === 0) {
      return [];
    }

    return data.filter(item => item[key].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLocaleLowerCase()));

  }
}
```

- You can use it in your view like that:

  ```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  <ul class="list-group">
   <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let user of users | filter:'result':'Failed'">{{ user.name }}</li>
  </ul>
  </div>

      <div class="col">
    <ul class="list-group">
              <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let user of users | filter:'result': 'Passed'">{{ user.name }}</li>
          </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: Please, include code within your answer rather than just links who may die in the future.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner Answer Updated

Answer (score 0):

You can create two methods on your component:

```
getPassedResults(): object[] {
  return this.studentResults.filter((r) => r.result === 'Passed');
}

getFailedResults(): object[] {
  return this.studentResults.filter((r) => r.result === 'Failed');
}
```

Then create variables which you can use the template:

```
const passedResults = this.getPassedResults();
const failedResults = this.getFailedResults();
```

Then in your template just loop through them like normal:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let result of passedResults">
  ...
  </li>
</ul>
```

Edit: Updated to clear up usage of method calls.

Comment: Calling methods from html is not a good idea. Angular Change Detection mechanism will call that method many times.